# Beautiful soup find gets results, however findall gets empy list

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use Beautiful Soup to parse an XBRL document (a standard tagged XML). I was trying to find all the elements with the tag "iic-com:inversionesfinancierasrvcotizada". When I use the function find it returns a result, the first of the desired entries.

```
soup.find('iic-com:inversionesfinancierasrvcotizada')
```

returns the XML

```
<iic-com:inversionesfinancierasrvcotizada>
<iic-com:codigoisin contextref="FIM_T12018_V86902186_ia">ES0105130001</iic-com:codigoisin>
<iic-com:inversionesfinancierasdescripcion contextref="FIM_T12018_V86902186_ia">GLOBAL DOMINION ACCESS SA</iic-com:inversionesfinancierasdescripcion>
<dgi-lc-int:xcode_iso4217.eur contextref="FIM_T12018_V86902186_da">EUR</dgi-lc-int:xcode_iso4217.eur>
<iic-com:inversionesfinancierasimporte>
<iic-com:inversionesfinancierasvalor contextref="FIM_T12018_V86902186_ia" decimals="2" unitref="euro">190490</iic-com:inversionesfinancierasvalor>
<iic-com:inversionesfinancierasporcentaje contextref="FIM_T12018_V86902186_ia" decimals="2" unitref="pure">0.10</iic-com:inversionesfinancierasporcentaje>
</iic-com:inversionesfinancierasimporte>
<iic-com:inversionesfinancierasimporte>
<iic-com:inversionesfinancierasvalor contextref="FIM_T12018_V86902186_ipy" decimals="2" unitref="euro">185545</iic-com:inversionesfinancierasvalor>
<iic-com:inversionesfinancierasporcentaje contextref="FIM_T12018_V86902186_ipy" decimals="2" unitref="pure">0.11</iic-com:inversionesfinancierasporcentaje>
</iic-com:inversionesfinancierasimporte>
</iic-com:inversionesfinancierasrvcotizada>
```

However, when I try the find_all or findAll methods I would expect to see this entry plus other additional entries, yet the result is.

```
soup.find_all('iic-com:inversionesfinancierasrvcotizada')
```

Yielding

```
[]
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong in here.

**EDIT**: If you want to try the full example, first you would need to get the document from [here](https://www.cnmv.es/Portal/Consultas/IIC/Fondo.aspx?nif=V86902186&vista=1&fs=30/04/2018) downloading the first XBRL document under 2018, Trimestre 1. I've downloaded and named it "trueval.XML". Then the code I used for reading was:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import io

soup = bs(io.open("trueval.XML", encoding="ISO-8859-1"), "html.parser")
```

Comment: *Might* be a problem with a particular parser. Did you try [other parsers](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)?

Comment: try `findAll` instead of `find_all`

Answer (score 1):

The solution I'm giving is not an efficient one but It should get you there. I used selector within my script. Gitve it a shot:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

element = """
<iic-com:inversionesfinancierasrvcotizada>
<iic-com:codigoisin contextref="FIM_T12018_V86902186_ia">ES0105130001</iic-com:codigoisin>
<iic-com:inversionesfinancierasdescripcion contextref="FIM_T12018_V86902186_ia">GLOBAL DOMINION ACCESS SA</iic-com:inversionesfinancierasdescripcion>
<dgi-lc-int:xcode_iso4217.eur contextref="FIM_T12018_V86902186_da">EUR</dgi-lc-int:xcode_iso4217.eur>
<iic-com:inversionesfinancierasimporte>
<iic-com:inversionesfinancierasvalor contextref="FIM_T12018_V86902186_ia" decimals="2" unitref="euro">190490</iic-com:inversionesfinancierasvalor>
<iic-com:inversionesfinancierasporcentaje contextref="FIM_T12018_V86902186_ia" decimals="2" unitref="pure">0.10</iic-com:inversionesfinancierasporcentaje>
</iic-com:inversionesfinancierasimporte>
<iic-com:inversionesfinancierasimporte>
<iic-com:inversionesfinancierasvalor contextref="FIM_T12018_V86902186_ipy" decimals="2" unitref="euro">185545</iic-com:inversionesfinancierasvalor>
<iic-com:inversionesfinancierasporcentaje contextref="FIM_T12018_V86902186_ipy" decimals="2" unitref="pure">0.11</iic-com:inversionesfinancierasporcentaje>
</iic-com:inversionesfinancierasimporte>
</iic-com:inversionesfinancierasrvcotizada>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(element, 'lxml')
for item in soup.select("[contextref^='FIM_T']"):
    print(item.text)
```

The result it produces:

```
ES0105130001
GLOBAL DOMINION ACCESS SA
EUR
190490
0.10
185545
0.11
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately this does not work for me, pretty much all the elements inside the large XBRL have a context reference such as that. The only thing that is unique to them is the tag name iic-com:inversionesfinancierasrvcotizada which defines each one of the small trees with the desired data inside, since each tree would be an entry